# how to get the enum values of a field in cakephp 2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

how to get enum values of a field  in cakephp 2

In 1.3 i could have got it easily with `_schema array`

Comment: not yet tried once i try it will let you know

Comment: doest your solution run a query

Comment: No, since getColumnType() uses the cached table schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// get column type
$type = $this->Model->getColumnType('field');

// extract values in single quotes separated by comma
preg_match_all("/'(.*?)'/", $type, $enums);

// enums
var_dump($enums[1]);
```

Comment: i went with substring b/w 6 and -2  and then explode on ','

Comment: would you like to share any such hidden gems